# Using parameter with table alias in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm new to node-postgres and trying to pass in parameters connected to a table alias, but it's not working. How can I parameterize the simple query below? Take something like

```
const pgQuery = 'SELECT t1.YEAR as year, t1.CODE as code FROM data t1;';
```

and instead do something like

```
const pgQuery = 'SELECT t1.$1 as year, t1.$2 as code FROM data t1;';
const values = ['YEAR', 'CODE'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs here:

https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

> PostgreSQL does not support parameters for identifiers. If you need to have dynamic database, schema, table, or column names (e.g. in DDL statements) use pg-format package for handling escaping these values to ensure you do not have SQL injection!

Which takes you here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format

Repo:

https://github.com/datalanche/node-pg-format